# "all guts" meaning in this sentence

Tags: meaning, word-usage

This is spoken by a man describing a certain brand of a car.
He said, "Pretty straightforward apple pie car, all guts."

What does "all guts" mean in this sentence?

And the following sentence starts with "Guts that, in part, come from a multi-generational work-force."

Is the second "guts" different from the first one?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

- "Pretty straightforward apple pie car, all guts."*

> guts plural : the inner essential parts
> “the guts of a car“

From Merriam-Webster, definition 2.

As @Bitter dreggs says, an engine on wheels.

Thus, no comfort or amenities like leather seats, genuine wood dashboard, high-end audio system, auto-connect to cell phone.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a metaphor within a metaphor.

The word "guts" is often used metaphorically to mean "bravery", so if someone says that a car is "all guts", that makes me think they're saying that the car has a lot of bravery.

But, of course, if someone says that a car has a lot of bravery, then that's another metaphor. They're saying that the car is powerful, or durable, or that it makes the driver feel brave, or something like that.

The following sentence seems to be saying that the "bravery" of the car comes from a multi-generational workforce. But that sentence also has a double meaning. The word "guts" often refers to the parts inside of a car (the parts that people don't often see), so the sentence is also saying that the inner parts of the car are made by a multi-generational workforce.

Another possibility, as [Bitter dreggs](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/61803/bitter-dreggs) mentioned, is that the "guts" of the car—meaning the inner parts, or, more specifically, probably the engine—are the biggest or most important feature of the car. Maybe the person is trying to say that when the car was designed, most of the effort went into giving it a powerful engine (rather than making it comfortable or affordable).

As for the phrase "apple pie car"... well, Americans often think of apple pie as being a great traditional American food, so I'm guessing that the man wants to say that the car is a great traditional American car.

Are these sentences from an American TV commercial? The metaphors sound strange, but they definitely sound like the sort of metaphors that would be in a TV commercial.

Comment: "Pretty straightforward", "apple pie", and "all guts" all refer to the fact that the car is a very simple build. No extras. (And absolutely nothing with bravery. Bravery is not straightforward, and bravery is definitely no apple pie.)